# Wrong variable type in WCF request ends up with service exception

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, xml-serialization

I have a WCF service with XmlSerializer used to serialize/deserialize requests and responses.
Is there any way to ommit service exceptions when string value is passed into field of type int (generally - incorrect variable type is passed) .
I know that in java webservice such situation ends up without exception - is it possible in wcf?
Currently I receive such exception:

```
<faultstring xml:lang="pl-PL">Error in deserializing body of request message for operation ''.</faultstring>
```

**Edit:**
Maybe I should use any overriden XmlSerializer in wcf to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please post the contract of your service and tell a little bit more why would you want to pass string when int is expected?

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio go to Menu:

Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions

*uncheck as needed*